# Switched from snap Docker to .deb, can't stop my containers

Tags: 18.10, snap, docker, apparmor

I can start Docker containers just fine, but when I try to stop or kill them, I get an error:

```
$ docker kill upbeat_shannon 
Error response from daemon: Cannot kill container: upbeat_shannon: Cannot kill container 3b9abdd8cf45d4e8bacd2980a2b6a0be2bc6915642818d46f6acf8347545fcd2: unknown error after kill: docker-runc did not terminate sucessfully: container_linux.go:387: signaling init process caused "permission denied"
: unknown
```

My situation is very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50482315/docker-compose-down-fails-due-to-permission-denied in that I had previously installed the snap version of Docker, before switching to the `docker.io` .deb package. And it appears that my issue is being caused by apparmor:

```
$ sudo apparmor_status
apparmor module is loaded.
58 profiles are loaded.
51 profiles are in enforce mode.
   [ ... lines omitted ... ]
   snap.docker.compose
   snap.docker.docker
   snap.docker.dockerd
   snap.docker.help
   snap.docker.hook.install
   snap.docker.hook.post-refresh
   snap.docker.machine
```

So it looks like the Docker snap left some profiles behind on my machine, and they are still being enforced. But I already uninstalled the snap, and I have no idea how to clean these up.

Answer (score 1):

I restarted my computer and that seems to have fixed the issue.

I had restarted my computer previously, so I'm not sure why this restart fixed it. Some things I did before restarting:

- `sudo systemctl restart apparmor.service`
- `sudo apparmor_parser --purge-cache`
- Re-installed and re-removed the Docker snap
- Reinstalled apparmor

Maybe one of those did something? Maybe not?